# Configure KVM in Debian 9 and bridge network remove Wi-Fi and not working

Tags: linux, debian, networking, kvm, bridge

I'm trying to install and configure KVM in Debian following [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-kvm-server-debian-linux-9-headless-server/). When I restart the network after configuring `/etc/network/interfaces.d/br0` my wi-fi connection goes off. I've noticed that if I remove the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/br0` file and then restart the network it reappears.

Here the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/br0` configuration:

```bsh
## make sure all config related to eth0 deleted ##
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.86        ## set up/netmask/broadcast/gateway as per your setup
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    bridge_ports wlp2s0    # replace eth0 with your actual interface name
    bridge_stp off       # disable Spanning Tree Protocol
    bridge_waitport 0    # no delay before a port becomes available
    bridge_fd 0          # no forwarding delay
```

and my network addresses etc:

```bsh
ip a s
### OUTPUT:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a3:cc:8c:22:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.86/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 85503sec preferred_lft 85503sec
    inet6 fe80::b6b:434f:6c9b:4b8c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
#############################
ip route | grep default
### OUTPUT :
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600
```

Here my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```bsh
cat /etc/network/interfaces
### OUTPUT :
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Moreover, I removed also the `/root/bridged.xml` that the instruction said to create, but if I list all the active network setting for KVM it still says:

```bsh
sudo virsh net-list --all
### OUTPUT:
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 br0                  active     yes           yes
 default              inactive   no            yes
```

I am not an expert in networking etc, I tried to look for solutions on internet but nothing worked...is there any mismatch? Any little "theory" about what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If your wifi interface `wlp2s0` is in STA (usual client) mode rather than AP (is the access point providing access for other devices), then you can't use it in a bridge. This is a limitation on how is working Wifi: your AP expects a 3-addresses mode, while bridging (and not being the AP) requires [4-addresses mode](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header). Home routers seldom can do this (nor your own card unless ath9k or other similar tinkerable device). The guide you are following uses ethernet, not wifi.

Comment: A workaround would be to use [ipvlan](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ipvlan.txt). It's not very compatible with DHCP